# How do I specify the path to the firefox binary using protractor and marionette?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-io

I was using directConnect before and I could specify the firefoxPath to launch a specific binary. Now that directConnect no longer works with Firefox > 47, I'm switching over to using marionette and firefoxPath isn't working anymore.

This is what my protractor config looks like right now.

```js
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

const firefoxProfile = new firefox.Profile();

const config = {
  specs: ['e2e/scenarios.js'],
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  framework: 'jasmine',
};

switch (process.env.BROWSER) {
  case 'firefox':
    firefoxProfile.setPreference('media.navigator.permission.disabled', true);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference('media.navigator.streams.fake', true);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference('media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains',
      'localhost,adam.local');

    config.capabilities = {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      marionette: true,
      firefox_profile: firefoxProfile,
    };
    break;
  case 'chrome':
  default:
    config.capabilities = {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ['auto-select-desktop-capture-source="Entire screen"',
          'use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
          'use-fake-ui-for-media-stream', 'disable-popup-blocking'],
        binary: process.env.BROWSERBIN,
      },
    };
    break;
}

exports.config = config;
```

This all seems to work fine, even specifying the preferences but I can't get the browser binary to work. I've tried firefoxPath and firefox_bin in the capabilities. Neither seem to work. Do I need to specify the path when I start webdriver-manager now that webdriver-manager is launching the browser?

I'm using protractor 5.1.1, webdriver-manager 12.0.2.

Answer (score -1):

if you are you are using latest version of firefox you need to set properties for geckodriver below is the code in java

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Jar's\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Hope this helps, if any question on this please leave a comment , happy to help :)

Comment: I want to set the path to the firefox binary, not the gecko driver. I also am using Protractor in Node, not Java.